# Installing zlib locally

Tags: linux, path

I have to install the `zlib` for a software to run in my institute server. I know I can install the `zlib` locally by using .

```
/configure --prefix=/home/local/zlib
```

I installed it finally by using `make install` command. Now I needed to put this in path to run the other software which requires `zlib`. How I can set the path?

I tried to use the export path using command `export PATH="$PATH:/home/local/zlib"` but I believe I don't have the root access so I cannot set that. Can some tell me any solution for this.

Comment: Sorry, this is not on topic for Server Fault. As a programming question, you probably meant to post at our sister site [so] instead - though it has been asked many times there, so a short search should find your answer.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?  I am running into the same issue.  I installed zlib locally and set up $PATH, $PKG_CONFIG_PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include $HOME/local/zlib but still getting ` warning: zlib.h: No such file or directory` error.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to /home/local/zlib/lib instead of `PATH`. You should be able to run the export command, since it will effect only your own session.

Comment: Thanks .. I tried LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/local/zlib/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH , but it didn't work.

Comment: checking for unsigned long long int... yes
checking for gzread in -lz... no
configure: error: zlib not found, see http://www.zlib.net
configure: error: ./configure failed for src/libGkArrays

Comment: Try setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to: /home/local/zlib/lib/pkgconfig

Answer (score 0):

you can add a symlink of zlib to your PATH using the following instruction:

Here is some information about adding a directory to your PATH:

The PATH variable can be accessed by typing

```
$PATH
```

Or, to see the directories in your path one-per-line, use

```
sed 's/:/\n/g' <<< "$PATH"
```

These are all the directories that the shell will look in to find the executable you've specified. I like to put symlinks for program executables that I have manually installed in
/home/myusername/.local/bin

In theory, you could add any directory with a program executable to your PATH, but it is easier/cleaner and less likely to cause problems if you keep a single desired directory like this, and then use symlinks to add executables.

To add the desired directory to your PATH, you will have to edit the ~/.bashrc file, and add the line:
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/desired/directory"
specifying whichever directory you want to add to the end of the PATH. Then in the shell, use the source command to load the new path to the current shell (starting a new shell session will also work):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, to add an executable to this directory, you will want to use a symbolic link, or symlink:

```
ln -s /path/to/executable /desired/path
```

Here is an example for the program BWA, where the executable bwa is in a folder called soft/bwa/:

```
ln -s /home/myusername/soft/bwa/bwa /home/myusername/.local/bin/bwa
```